# pst-optexp: Trouble in drawing collimated beam

Tags: pstricks, pst-optexp

I want to draw a Z-Scan experimental setup. My lab's DPSS Laser has a beam radius of some value, and I change this value by using a simple telescope. It was supposed to be easy to draw this using pst-optexp package. Problem is I can't find the correct focal lengths to collimate the beam again. Here's an example of what I'm saying:

[image: example]

As one can easily see, the beam is not exactly leaving the last lens perfectly collimated. It's still diverging a little bit, like I'm making some mistake in positioning the lenses. Problem is I've set them to have lensradius=1 and lensradius=2, and it doesn't seem that in this case the focal length is exactly 1. It seems to be a little offset, a little longer than 1.

If someone could help me with a solution to draw collimated beams, I would appreciate.

My code to generate the image was written as follows (sorry for the mess):

```
\documentclass[]{revtex4} 

\usepackage{pst-optexp}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}

    \pnodes(1,1){S}(0,3){A}(11,5){BS}(13,1){M1}(13,5){M2}(1,1){S}
    \pnodes(4,1){L1}(7,1){L2}(1,5){D1}(11,7){D2}(3,1){P}(10,5){L3}
    \psset{mirrortype=extended, mirrordepth=0.2}

    \begin{optexp}
        \optsource[innerlabel](S)(P){DPSS}
        \polarization[poltype=parallel] (S)(P)
        \lens[compname=L1,lensradius=2] (L1)(L1)
        \lens[compname=L2,lensradius=1] (L2)(L2)
        \mirror[compname=M1](S)(M1)(M2)
        \mirror[compname=M2](M1)(M2)(BS)
        \optdetector[compname=Det1](BS)(D1)
        \drawwidebeam[beamwidth=0.4,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green!20!white]
            (S){L1}{L2}{M1}{M2}{Det1}
    \end{optexp}

 \end{pspicture}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: try  `(7.1,1){L2}`

Comment: It looks like it works, but the beam still isn't quite collimated. This solution should be decent enough if I can't find a proper way to set the beam accurately collimated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you have different options to adjust the beam path in such a situation: fine tune the position of the second lens, or its refractive index. Or you can define the beam path piecewise, see the telescope example in chapter 9.5 of the documentation.

```
\documentclass[]{revtex4} 

\usepackage{pst-optexp}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}
    \pnodes(1,1){S}(0,3){A}(11,5){BS}(13,1){M1}(13,5){M2}(1,1){S}
    \pnodes(4,1){L1}(7,1){L2}(1,5){D1}(11,7){D2}(3,1){P}(10,5){L3}
    \psset{mirrortype=extended, mirrordepth=0.2}
    \addtopsstyle{Beam}{fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=green!20!white}
    \begin{optexp}
        \optsource[innerlabel](S)(P){DPSS}
        \polarization[poltype=parallel] (S)(P)
        \lens[compname=L1,lensradius=2] (L1)(L1)
        \lens[compname=L2,lensradius=1] (L2)(L2)
        \mirror[compname=M1](S)(M1)(M2)
        \mirror[compname=M2](M1)(M2)(BS)
        \optdetector[compname=Det1](BS)(D1)
        \drawwidebeam[beamwidth=0.4, beaminsidelast](S){L1}{L2}
        \drawwidebeam[loadbeampoints]{L2}{M1}{M2}{Det1}
    \end{optexp}

 \end{pspicture}

 \end{document}
```

That traces a first beam until the last interface of `L2`. The end position is saved internally, because `savebeampoints` is `true` by default. Now, the second beam can load the end points of the first beam with `loadbeampoints`, but now the beam divergence is zero and you have a perfectly collimated beam.

[image]

Comment: I have been thinking about this for a while, and even though your example and the documentation's one do actually work, I'm still having some trouble. When I add another optical components, such as another convergent lens after M2, the new loaded, collimated, beam doesn't act correctly in the presence of the new lens. How should I proceed?

Comment: Please use the option  `useNA=true` when debugging. That shows rays also when they miss a given target (that was at least my problem when I added a lens midway between last mirror and detector)

Comment: I see the problem now. The beam was not hitting any target. When I place the detector near the lens, I can see the light acting normal and it works perfectly. Trouble I'm having now is I can't actually place the detector near the lens. I'm thinking about a solution to my problem, since in Z Scan we need Fraunhofer limit, where the detector is far away from the third lens' focus. Maybe if I put some ghost screen to see the beam diverging. But I think it's subject to another question. The beam is already collimated and working just fine. If you want to follow the other question, I'd be glad.